# Problem with booting Windows 7 alongside Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 alongside my Windows 7 Professional. Now Ubuntu works great but I can't boot Windows. When I try to boot it, the screen of choosing system reappears like I had restarted my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Once you logged into Ubuntu try installing [gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted)

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

and post the image along with the question.

Also in case grub2 is not identifying your Windows 7 partition, you need to try boot repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then you can post the pastebin contents and one can look into it to find out the exact issue.

BTW make sure that Ubuntu is installed in the same mode as Windows 7 Professional for e.g. if Windows 7 is installed in UEFI mode - Ubuntu should also be installed in the same manner. Also make sure that Secure boot is completely disabled in BIOS.